# non-random hemisphere sample in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently using a sampling method for tracing rays and I use this bit of code which samples a random point on an hemisphere and outputs a vector:

```
vec3 CosWeightedRandomHemisphereDirection( vec3 n, float rand1, float rand2 )
{
    float Xi1 = rand1;
    float Xi2 = rand2;

    float  theta = acos(sqrt(1.0-Xi1));
    float  phi = 2.0 * 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 * Xi2;

    float xs = sin(theta) * cos(phi);
    float ys = cos(theta);
    float zs = sin(theta) * sin(phi);

    vec3 y = n;
    vec3 h = y;
    if (abs(h.x)<=abs(h.y) && abs(h.x)<=abs(h.z))
        h.x= 1.0;
    else if (abs(h.y)<=abs(h.x) &&abs(h.y)<=abs(h.z))
        h.y= 1.0;
    else
        h.z= 1.0;

    vec3 x = normalize(cross(h,y));
    vec3 z = normalize(cross(x,y));

    vec3 direction = xs * x + ys * y + zs * z;
    return normalize(direction);
}
```

now, in case I wanted the samples to always have a fixed position relative to the hemisphere such as [those vectors](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FWGnacfrQ2o/UQVQNYhEj9I/AAAAAAAAAkw/99C0J8G-1Rk/s1600/coneTraceDir.png) which have been sampled at 60° each from an hemisphere, how do I adapt the code? I have the vectors saved in an array. 
So my function would have a header like

```
vec3 FixedHemisphereDirection( vec3 n, vec3 sampleDir)
```

where sampleDir is one of the 6 fixed directions
Also, since the positions are going to be fixed, can the code be optimized?

EDIT:

I noticed that the directions are working only for normals that point up or down, but not the rest (it took me a while to notice because I kept using the random directions). Here is the code as I am using it now.

```
    vec3 FixedHemisphereDirection( vec3 n, vec3 sampleDir)
{
    vec3 x;
    vec3 z;

    if(abs(n.x) < abs(n.y)){
        if(abs(n.x) < abs(n.z)){
            x = vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        }else{
            x = vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        }
    }else{
        if(abs(n.y) < abs(n.z)){
            x = vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        }else{
            x = vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        }
    }

    z = normalize(cross(x,n));
    x = cross(n,z);

    mat3 M = mat3(  x.x, n.x, z.x,
                    x.y, n.y, z.y,
                    x.z, n.z, z.z);
    return M*sampleDir;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it just randomly picking one of the six vectors?

Comment: well no because the template vector (0,1,0) points up in the sample sphere but when I use it it will have to point in the same direction as the normal. The others have to point accordingly

Comment: Ah, that's supposed to be a normal. Wait a second, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single normal is not enough to uniquely identify the local coordinate system of the hemisphere. It can be rotated in any direction about that normal.

We first need to construct the local coordinate system. Therefore, we need the local x and z axis. The y axis is already given by the normal. All axes should be orthogonal to each other. So we can do the following:

```
x := (1, 0, 0)
z := normalize(cross(x, n))
x := cross(n, z)
```

If the normal is parallel to `(1, 0, 0)`, you should choose another x-axis, because the cross product will be zero.

From these axes, we can construct a transformation matrix:

```
     / x.x  n.x  z.x \
M := | x.y  n.y  z.y |
     \ x.z  n.z  z.z /
```

This is the matrix that transforms the six given directions to directions in the hemisphere specified by `n`.

```
dir := randomly pick on of the six directions
return M * dir
```

Comment: hey sorry to bother you, I added an edit because I noticed a problem, can you check it please?

Comment: Looks good to me. Have you called the matrix constructor correctly? I.e. might the order of entries be transposed, so `(x.x, x.y, x.z ...)`?